# Error when defining inner classes in a Test class in JUnit

Tags: java, reflection, junit, inner-classes, junit3

I'm having some problems when defining inner classes in a Test class inherited from TestCase, for JUnit 3. Scenario is like following:

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
  public void method() { ... }
}
```

FooTest.java

```
public class FooTest extends TestCase {
  public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void method() { ... }
  }
  public void testMethod() { ... }
}
```

Now, if I run this from Eclipse, the tests run ok, but if I try to run from an Ant task it fails:

[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class Foo$Bar has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()

Bar is NOT a Test class, it's just a subclass of Foo overriding some method that I don't need to do the real stuff when testing.

I'm quite lost at the moment and I don't know how to approach this problem. Is the only way to create the subclasses as standalone?

Comment: What is your Ant configuration for running tests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because you included a nested class into junit fileset.
Add an "excludes" property to your build.xml.

For example:

```
<target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit>
        <batchtest todir="${test.build.dir}" unless="testcase">
            <fileset dir="${test.build.classes}"
                includes = "**/Test*.class"
                excludes = "**/*$*.class"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution than @Ignore, as the inner classes does not show up at all in test results files when they're excluded in build.xml. Both solutions work though.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you helped me understand why ant's junit test was barfing just because I have a private inner class. The exclude statement did the trick.

Comment: I happen to be using a `<fileset>` with a nested `<patternset>` with a `refid`. You can't change the `<patternset>` but you can still put an `<exclude name="**/*$*.class" />` element inside the `<fileset>` to remove the inner classes that the `<patternset>` would have included.

Answer (score 5):

You could try defining the Bar class as static:

```
public class FooTest extends TestCase {
  public static class Bar extends Foo {
    public void method() { ... }
  }
  public void testMethod() { ... }
}
```

... but the fact that it works in one environment but not in another suggests one of two things:

1. Java version
2. Classpath
3. [Edit: as suggested by Jim below] Different versions of junit.jar

Comment: +1 I'd add one more: different versions of junit.jar.  It's possible an older version of JUnit is confused by the nested non-static class.

Answer (score 4):

I'm feeling like a necrposter, but the thing is that I've ran into similar problem with maven today.

Usual `mvn test` runs well but when I want run tests from specific package like `mvn test -Dtest=com.test.*` - `initializationError` is thrown. This "works" for both Junit 3 and 4.

I found the reason for my maven-case, this may be the same for ant.
The thing is: by default maven's test plugin (surefire that is) considers only specific subset of all classes as "test-classes", namely searching them by name, like *Test and so on (you can read about this at [surefire's home page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)).When we define `test` property we completely override default behavior. This means that with `-Dtest=com.test.*` surefire will pick up not only `com.test.MyTestClass` but also `com.test.MyTestClass.InnerClass` and even `com.test.MyTestClass$1` (i.e. anonymous classes).

So in order to run e.g. classes from some package you should use something like `-Dtest=com.test.*Test` (if you use suffixes for identifying test-classes of course).

Answer (score 4):

You can also annotate the nested class @Ignore if you don't want to exclude all inner classes.

Comment: This does not work for anonymous inner classes. @Ignore Annotation is invalid here.

Comment: True, but the question wasn't about anonymous inner classes.