# How to write inner test classes if you use Spring and Junit 4? Or How else I can structure my tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a test class which in the future will test different conditions for tests and I'd like to make it more structured and fit only into one file. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758294/test-cases-in-inner-classes-with-junit) solution but it doesn't suit me because I can't combine a `SpringRunner.class` and `Enclosed.class` to fit it into one `@RunWith`. I can't use `Nitor Creation's Nested Runner` - it brings the same problem.

I use `Spring 5` and `Junit 4.12`. Well... my question is, how to combine my tests inside a few inner/nested classes with one root class?

**UPD:** one remark - I can't make an upgrade to `Junit 5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JUnit 4**

If you need to stick with JUnit 4, you can use a third-party plugin to provide support. See the [junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner](https://github.com/bechte/junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner/wiki) provided by `bechte` on GitHub.

Add the dependency to your project, and use the `HeirachalContextRunner` like so:

```
@RunWith(HierarchicalContextRunner.class)
public class NestedTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule  springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // General test-suite setup
    }

    public class NestedClass {

        @Test
        public void testSomething() {
            // Test
        }

        public class AnotherNestedClass {

            @Test
            public void testSomethingElse() {
                // Test
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we don't need  to specify Spring's runner here. Instead, we use the rules to apply the Spring test framework, available as of `Spring 4.2`.

**JUnit 5**

Arguably a more future-proof solution would be to upgrade to `JUnit 5`. Then you can construct test cases straight out of the box, with the `@Nested` annotation. See below:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyNestedTest {

    @BeforeAll
    void setup() {
        // General test-suite setup
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("parentTestSuite")
    class NestedClass {

        @Test
        void testSomething() {
            // Test
        }

        @Nested
        @DisplayName("childTestSuite")
        class AnotherNestedClass {

            @Test
            void testSomethingElse() {
                // Test
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Note that `@RunWith` has been replaced with `@ExtendWith` in `JUnit 5`. If you choose to migrate to JUnit 5, you may find it useful to read [Baeldung's guide on JUnit 5 migration](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration).

Comment: I can't make an upgrade to Junit 5 and I should have labeled it.
I like this solution, I will keep it in mind. Thank you)

Comment: @Woods understood - see my recent edit for a JUnit 4 compatible solution using a third-party library.

Comment: @Woods the important thing to note is that you can use another runner if you replace your `SpringRunner` with Spring's JUnit rules (introduced in version `4.2`).

Comment: @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) is not required since it is included already in @SpringBootTest